# face recognition using opencv error savedmodule file does not exist at

Tags: python, opencv, face-recognition, face-detection, dlib

i have a university project where i have to make an app for face recognition using python, i tried to do it using libraries opencv, dlib..  but i have an error where its says file does not exist at: facenet_keras.h5
i tried to look for solutions but i didn't found any
please help, thank you

i think maybe i didn't setup the right path ?

here's a prt of the code

```
 # The pretrained model to extract embeddings
        self.emb_model = load_model('facenet_keras.h5', compile=False)

        # Output dataframe time
        if os.path.exists("report.csv"):
            self.report = pd.read_csv('report.csv')
        else:
            self.report = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ID', 'Name', 'Date', 'Time'])

        # Sample Amount to take
        self.samples_amount = 100
```

here's the following error:

```
File "c:/Users/nihad/Desktop/Face-Recognition-using-Face-Embeddings-main/main.py", line 606, in <module>
    main = Main()
  File "c:/Users/nihad/Desktop/Face-Recognition-using-Face-Embeddings-main/main.py", line 61, in __init__
    self.emb_model = load_model('facenet_keras.h5', compile=False)
  File "C:\Users\nihad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\saving\save.py", line 186, in load_model
    loader_impl.parse_saved_model(filepath)
  File "C:\Users\nihad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\saved_model\loader_impl.py", line 113, in parse_saved_model
    constants.SAVED_MODEL_FILENAME_PB))
OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at: facenet_keras.h5/{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}
[ WARN:0] global D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (438) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution

Method 1

it may be that the environment of the framework was destroyed after the model was imported, and the file path was changed, which can be solved by re installing py

pip3 uninstall h5py
pip3 installl h5py

Method 2: path problem

It seems that this solution has not been mentioned, but it has solved the problem
although the relative path can be used to run the model alone, it should be changed to absolute path.

[link](https://programmerah.com/oserror-savedmodel-file-does-not-exist-at-model-facenet_keras-h5-27164/)